# Regex to match specific keyword(s) AND 10 digit number in any order

Tags: regex

We've got this regular expression that matches when acct, account, or loan (case insensitive) is anywhere before a 10 digit number but we need to find matches whether the keyword(s) are before or after the 10 digit number.

```
\b(?i)(account|acct|loan)[\S\s]*\b\d{10}\b
```

Examples:

account 0123456789 - should match
0123456789 acct - should match
loan    0123456789 - should match

accounting 0123456789 - should NOT match
account 0123456789123 - should NOT match

We are only looking for matches when a specific keyword **AND** 10 digit number are present.

Comment: Add example input and outputs, please.

Comment: account    0123456789 - should trigger a match

Comment: as well as: 0123456789 account

Comment: Come on... add them properly to the question and don't expect people you are asking for help to gather the necessary information from comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Abbondanza original question updated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookaheads/lookbehinds. I actually recently found out how to do this.

```
(?=.*\b(acc(oun)?t|loan)\b)(?=.*\b(\d{10})\b)
```

Comment: Worked fine for me.

Comment: @mikeyq6 What? [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY5gN4/7) ..! Or  there is a misunderstood about the question for me.

Comment: It matches both cases in the demo. It just doesn't highlight them because there isn't a capturing group for the number. I think I'll make it one.

Comment: @RamenChef Your example works when there are any number of spaces or other words between the keyword and 10 digit number but not when carriage returns are introduced. How could I account for these?

Comment: Unless you're in JavaScript's crap regex engine, you should be able to add an `s` modifier to make the `.`s match line breaks. If you _are_ in JavaScript, you can swap out the `.`s for `[^]`s.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Just noticed that I've lost case insensitivity. Do you know what I would need to add and where I would put it? The example below matches on account but not Account. Thanks!

Comment: Case insensitivity can easily be done with the `i` modifier. Also, when I referred to the `s` modifier, I meant _globally_.

Answer (score 2):

You can stretch it out into 2 separate matching groups, ie:

```
/(account|acct|loan)[\S\s]*\d{10}$|\d{10}[\S\s]*(account|acct|loan)$/gim
```

Where the first half before the `|` matches the first case with the word before the number, and the second half matches the second case with the word after

See demo here:
https://regex101.com/r/nY5gN4/9

Comment: Using your link, it works perfectly for me. It will only match 'one' of the two possibilities though. If you remove or alter one of the 'account' words, it will match the other. Are you saying that you need to match both separately? It's not very clear from your question

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info all! To answer your question...yes we need to have any one of the keywords match as well as a 10 digit number.